# How do I hash specific columns from a csv file?

Tags: python, csv, hash

I'm trying to hash column 2 and 8 but I ended up hashing the entire file. What's the issue with my code?

```
import csv
import hashlib


with open('UserInfo.csv') as csvfile:

    with open('UserInfo_Hashed.csv', 'w') as newfile:

        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)

        for r in reader:

            hashing = hashlib.sha256((r['Password']).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()

            newfile.write(hashing + '\n')
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You code doesn't hash the entire file. It hashes the data in your `Password` column and writes the hash into `newfile`

Comment: but all the columns were hashed when i ran the code

Comment: then we are not talking about the same code

Comment: Why do you believe all the columns were hashed? Please add some code proving it.

Comment: Just added screenshot of both files

Comment: I really hope that's fake data

Comment: it's a homework

Comment: Ok... generate the sha256 hash from the first password (ZFE9...) from your csv file on this [site](https://hashgenerator.de/), make sure that you choose sha-256 algorithm. and then post the hash here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your code showing your attempt to hash the `Password` column only, the following code just does the hashing for the `Password` column.

```py
import csv
import hashlib

with open('UserInfo.csv') as csvfile:

    with open('UserInfo_Hashed.csv', 'w') as newfile:

        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)

        for i, r in enumerate(reader):
            #  writing csv headers
            if i is 0:
                newfile.write(','.join(r) + '\n')

            # hashing the 'Password' column
            r['Password'] = hashlib.sha256((r['Password']).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()

            # writing the new row to the file with hashed 'Password'
            newfile.write(','.join(r.values()) + '\n')
```

The issue with your code is with this line `newfile.write(hashing + '\n')`, as this writes only the hashed password to the file (without the other columns). Also you didn't write the CSV header to the new file.

---

I strongly suggest using `Pandas`:

```py
import pandas as pd
import hashlib

# reading CSV input
df = pd.read_csv('UserInfo.csv')

# hashing the 'Password' column
df['Password'] = df['Password'].apply(lambda x: \
        hashlib.sha256(x.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest())

# writing the new CSV output
df.to_csv('UserInfo_Hashed.csv', index=False)
```